# still can't find the #shibuya-faucet channel

Tags: astar

On the Astar Network'discord chnanel, I still can't find the #shibuya-faucet channel.I tried bellow action.anyone who can tell met the countermeasure? When I try to execute the contents of 3 and 4
I tried to do 3 and 4, but could not find the corresponding channels.

1. Join the Astar Network Discord server by visiting this link: https://discord.com/channels/644182966574252073/1097773162248278077
2. Once you have joined the server, you should see a list of channels on the left side of the Discord application.
3. Look for the `├──faucets` category, and expand it if needed.
4. Under this category, you should find the `#shibuya-faucet` channel.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To be able to view the channel, you need to verify yourself and get a role. Go to #verification.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.I've got a role(or tried )but,still can't see.so,I got cet on the portal and transfer to test wallet.thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Faucet channel is named `sby-faucet` under faucet category. Try looking again.

[image]

Comment: thanks.but,I can't see "sby-faucet" on my screen.but,I've got faucet on the Portal though.

Answer (score 0):

It is here, on the Portal. You will only be able to see the "faucet" button if your wallet is empty. If you already have some SBY in there, you can't request for more.

[image]

Comment: thanks.I got faucet.still can't find the #shibuya-faucet channel on discord though.thank you.